# Excel VBA - don't error out if criteria isn't found

Tags: excel, vba

As a brief explanation, I put together a script to help import weekly Google Analytics data from generated CSVs into one master workbook. There's the chance of more website accounts being added to this tracking system so I have another script that helps add the account in to make sure that everything is consistent across the spreadsheets/tables.

As for the actual importing, I have a "two-part" VBA script that is used to loop through all the CSVs in a folder, open them, import the data from the CSV into a master workbook, then delete the CSV upon successfully completing the loop before moving on to the next one. I have included an error statement to tell the user if the CSV that they're importing doesn't have a matching spreadsheet in the master workbook, so that it stops the script at that point to give them the chance to add that account to the workbook before proceeding.

However, some weeks particular websites might not have all the data and this is falsely causing the error message to appear telling the user that the account needs to be added to the site. If the CSV doesn't contain that data, it's because the data was essentially 0, and I want 0's to be entered into the row to make note that there was no activity that week, NOT give the user an error that they need to add the account to the workbook.

```
'THE FOLLOWING SCRIPT RUNS WHEN THE IMPORT ANALYTICS BUTTON IS CLICKED
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    'if at any point an error is encountered, display the Error Message (at end of script)
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg

    'Optimize Macro Speed by turning off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
      Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        With FldrPicker
          .Title = "Select A Target Folder That Contains Your Files"
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End With

    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
      myPath = myPath
      If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
      myExtension = "*.csv*"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
      myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
      Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
          wb.Activate
        'Ensure Workbook has opened and is active before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim sheet_name_result As String

    'sets the URL (minus the "# " in front) to be the search string
    strSearch = Right(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2"), Len(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")) - 2)

    'sets the data list URL column to be the searched range
    Set rng1 = Workbooks("Spokes- Google Analytics trends.xlsm").Worksheets("LISTS").Range("B:B").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlPart)
    sheet_name_result = rng1.Offset(0, -1).Value

        'LOOP THROUGH FOLLOWING CODE IF A MATCH IS FOUND
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            Dim table_list_object As ListObject
            Dim table_object_row As ListRow
            Set table_list_object = Workbooks("Spokes- Google Analytics trends.xlsm").Worksheets(sheet_name_result).ListObjects(1)
            Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

        'calculate pageviews
            Dim organic_pageviews As Integer
            Dim paid_pageviews As Integer
            Dim direct_pageviews As Integer
            Dim referral_pageviews As Integer
            Dim display_pageviews As Integer
            Dim sum_pageviews As Integer
            organic_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "organic", Range("C:C"))
            paid_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "paid", Range("C:C"))
            direct_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "direct", Range("C:C"))
            referral_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "referral", Range("C:C"))
            display_pageviews = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "display", Range("C:C"))
            sum_pageviews = organic_pageviews + paid_pageviews + direct_pageviews + referral_pageviews + display_pageviews

        'calculate visitors aka sessions
            Dim organic_visitors As Integer
            Dim paid_visitors As Integer
            Dim direct_visitors As Integer
            Dim referral_visitors As Integer
            Dim display_visitors As Integer
            Dim sum_visitors As Integer
            organic_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "organic", Range("F:F"))
            paid_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "paid", Range("F:F"))
            direct_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "direct", Range("F:F"))
            referral_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "referral", Range("F:F"))
            display_visitors = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "display", Range("F:F"))
            sum_visitors = organic_visitors + paid_visitors + direct_visitors + referral_visitors + display_visitors

        'calculate unique visitors aka new users
            Dim organic_new As Integer
            Dim paid_new As Integer
            Dim direct_new As Integer
            Dim referral_new As Integer
            Dim display_new As Integer
            Dim sum_new As Integer
            organic_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "organic", Range("E:E"))
            paid_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "paid", Range("E:E"))
            direct_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "direct", Range("E:E"))
            referral_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "referral", Range("E:E"))
            display_new = Application.SumIf(Range("A:A"), "display", Range("E:E"))
            sum_new = organic_new + paid_new + direct_new + referral_new + display_new

        'calculate pages/visit
            Dim pages_per_visit As String
            pages_per_visit = (sum_pageviews / sum_visitors) / 100
        'calculate organic traffic
            Dim organic_percent As String
            organic_percent = (organic_visitors / sum_visitors)

        'calculate referral traffic
            Dim referral_percent As String
            referral_percent = (referral_visitors / sum_visitors)

        'isolate start date
            Dim date_location As String
            Dim start_date_ugly As String
            Dim start_date_string As String

            date_location = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A4")
            start_date_ugly = Left(date_location, 10)
            start_date_string = Right(start_date_ugly, 8)

        'isolate end date
            Dim end_date_string As String

            end_date_string = Right(date_location, 8)

        'posts data to columns
            table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = DateSerial(Left(start_date_string, 4), Mid(start_date_string, 5, 2), Right(start_date_string, 2))
                table_object_row.Range(1, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = DateSerial(Left(end_date_string, 4), Mid(end_date_string, 5, 2), Right(end_date_string, 2))
                table_object_row.Range(1, 2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            table_object_row.Range(1, 3).Value = sum_pageviews
            table_object_row.Range(1, 4).Value = sum_visitors
            table_object_row.Range(1, 5).Value = sum_new
            table_object_row.Range(1, 6).Value = Format((pages_per_visit), Percent)
            table_object_row.Range(1, 7).Value = organic_percent
            table_object_row.Range(1, 8).Value = referral_percent

        Else
            'Informs user that the URL was not found (redundant, because script will default to Error Message if it encounters a problem)
            'It's better to have the error message end the script outside of the loop sequence because it will stop the loop at the problem URL,
            'allowing the user to add the URL manually, then click import again to pick up where they left off.
            MsgBox strSearch & " was not found."
        End If

    'sets the currently active workbook name as a variable called xFullName
    xFullName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

        'Closes and deletes workbook by name
          wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
          Kill xFullName
        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
          DoEvents

        'Get next file name
          myFile = Dir
      Loop


'END OF LOOP EVENTS

    'Message box when tasks are completed
      MsgBox "CSVs have been imported."

ResetSettings:
      'Reset Macro Optimization settings by turning on screen updating
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Exit Sub

'Error Message that script defaults to if it can't complete (ie: if it encounters a URL not in the database) and finishes script
ErrMsg:
    MsgBox strSearch & " is not in the spreadsheet. Please add it to the database before importing CSV data."
End Sub
```

EDIT: [Screenshot of CSV data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnccl.png) here's what the CSV looks like. If there is no data that week, that entire block of cells A7:H11 (there's actually one normally-present row missing from this screenshot, that isn't always the set cell range) is missing and A7 would instead start the Day Index table.

Comment: As you know, it's asking users to put the data into the spreadsheet, because of the `On Error Goto ErrMsg` line.  Is there a way for you to detect if the website doesn't have the data, as opposed to it needing to be added to the spreadsheet? If so, perhaps create another error handler, or just add an `If` statement looking for that, and fill in the data that way?

Comment: I've edited the original post to include a screenshot for help. I'm wondering about  putting an if statement to look and see if "Day Index" is in A7 to then inform the script that there is no data. From there I guess the values of the variables would be set to 0 within the import script (except the date range of course). Where would that if statement go in the script though? Does it wrap around the whole looped part?